# Calculus: continuous

Tags: calculus

Q: if $f$ is continuos on $[0,1]$ with $0\leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, prove that there exists $C \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=c$.

I don't understand why the following proof works:

$g(x)=f(x)-x$

$0<f(x)<1 $

$g(c)=0$

$f(c)-c=0$

$f(c)=c$

Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: At what point do you no longer understand the proof?

Comment: I don't understand it from the beginning step

Comment: There are many words missing, so many that what is written cannot be considered a proof, or even close to a proof.

Comment: The first line defines a new function $g$ with domain $[0,1]$ by the formula $g(x) = f(x) - x$. The rest of the proof consists of applying the intermediate value theorem to $g$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get rid of the easy cases. if $(f(0) = 0,$ then $c = 0$ and you are done. in the same way if $f(1) = 1,$ then $c = 1.$

so now we are left to deal with the case of $f$ such that $f(0) > 0$ and $f(1) < 1.$
consider the function $g$ defined by $g(x) = f(x) - x.$  see that $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $g(0) = f(0) > 0, g(1) = f(1) - 1 < 0.$  by the intermediate value theorem, there is a $c$ between $0$ and $1$ such that $g(c) = 0.$ that is $f(c) = c$

to see geometrically this fact, consider the unit square $A = (0,0), B = (1,0), 
C = (0,1), D = (0,1).$ the graph of $f$ starts on the side $AD$ and ends up on the side $BC.$ the graph must necessarily cross the diagonal $AC.$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $g(0) = f(0) \geq 0$ and $g(1) = f(1)-1 \leq 0$. If either one of these is actually equal to zero, then you're done. Otherwise, $g(0) > 0$ and $g(1) < 0$, so by the intermediate value theorem there is $c \in (0,1)$ with $g(c)=0$. The rest is algebra.

Comment: Thank you so much for your swift reply!! Yet, I don't understand why let g(c) = 0?

Comment: @BellasmiliT If you do not understand part of a user's answer (or are not fully satisfied with it), then do not accept such an answer. Or at least communicate with the user via comments to increase understanding. If you gain this, *then* accept the answer. :)

Comment: Oh! Gotcha! Sorry about it because I just start to use this website:) yet, many thanks!!!

Comment: @BellasmiliT You get that $g(c)=0$ because $g$ is continuous. Intuitively, at $0$, $g$ is positive; at $1$, $g$ is negative. So the graph of $g$ has to go through zero somewhere, which I'm calling $c$. If no such $c$ existed, there would have to be a jump, which would destroy the continuity.

Answer (score 2):

It is by the Intermediate Value Theorem as to why the solution you provided work.

The Intermediate Value Theorem states that if we suppose $f$ to be a continuous function on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and let $L$ be any number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, where $f(a) \neq f(b)$, then there exists a number $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=L$.

Now in your case that interval is $[0,1]$ and we want to show that there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c)=c$.

The line $g(x)=f(x)-x$ tells you the function you are given. Then $0 \leq f(x)\leq1$ says the function $f$ is in the interval $[0,1]$. We don't really know what $f$ and $g$ represents, but we do know $g(x)=f(x)-x$, which tells us if we plug in $c$ we get $g(c)=f(c)-c=0$, hence $f(c)=c$.

Again, we don't really know $f$ and $g$ represents, but we can observe the following case:

$$g(0)=f(0)\geq0$$ 
$$g(1)=f(1)-1\leq0$$
by which we note that if $g(0)=0$ or $g(1)=0$ then we have shown that there exists a number $c$ such that $g(c)=f(c)-c=0$, hence $f(c)=c$. Now if $g(0)\neq0$ and $g(1)\neq0$, we consider the following case:
$$g(0)>0$$
$$g(1)<0$$
which tells us $g$ $\textit{must}$ cross the the x-axis where $y=0$, since $g$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ that changes from a positive value to a negative value (or vice versa), thus showing the existence of a number $c$ such that $g(c)=f(c)-c=0$, hence $f(c)=c$ somewhere within the interval $(0,1)$.